Failed to resolve import "../assets" from "src/components/Header.jsx"
I am working through this tutorial on YouTube, but at the same time modifying it to fit my needs. When I try to import an image, I am running in this error:
"[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "../assets" from "src/components/Header.jsx". Does the file exist?"
Here is my setup. As you can see the folder and image are there.

My other imports are working just fine, so I am at a loss as to how to resolve it.
New to React here. :)

Edit: Showing how it doesn't appear to even think the assets folder exists.


From error you can predict that path is incorrect or there is problem in the way you are importing image, may be try importing like
import logo from '@/src/assets/logo.png.
or
import logo from "./assets/logo.png".
You are destruturing it from folder, which is not possible as you can desrtucture from file that is exporting something.
Please refer this article for more information, https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

I tried to import it both of those ways an neither of them worked.

Try with one dot only.

Still does not work. It's like it doesn't find the folder. Added an image above, showing that ...

You don't need to put logo in curly brakets.

That does not work. It still behaves as if the folder does NOT exist.

Does suggestion grabbing right folder when you try to import the file?

No. The suggestions do not even show the folder when I try to import the file.
